How to adjust the alignment of links in the navbar in small view in Bootstrap 5
I previously asked a question about the Bootstrap 5 navbar here:
Adjust navbar height to be smaller
and I did receive answers that were helpful. Thank you. I do have a follow-up question:
I would like to change the alignment of the links in small view.
This is what I have:
<header>
    <div class="container fixed-top bg-white py-3">
      <header class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
        <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"/></svg>
          <span class="fs-4">Portfolio</span>
        </a>
  
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">PowerPoint</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Infographics</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Logos and Icons</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Web Design</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </header>

This is how it currently looks:

I would like it to look like this:

What I tried was with a separate css file for the smallest view:
@media (min-width: 0px) {
.nav-link-powerpoint{
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 86px;
    }

    .nav-link-infographic {
      margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 39px;
    }

That did fix the horizontal alignment:

but now it seemed to override the vertical alignment and the text-decoration-none in this section:
<a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none">

Is there a way to align it vertically like this (the red line is to show the alignment) :

But without the underline for the links. Is there a better way to do this?
Thank you,
--
Updated Screen Capture:


Use flex.
.nav is already a flex element. Apply flex: 0 0 150px or whatever width fits your use case.
In other words, you need
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: 150px;

This way your elements remain aligned and will always have the same width (child elements cannot grow and cannot shrink).


.nav-item {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  display: flex;
}
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">PowerPoint</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Infographics</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Logos and Icons</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Web Design</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">




Thank you for your answer. I tried what you wrote. It does align the links but it aligns the links in three rows with two links per row in small view and the active link is a little large. Is there way to make the active link smaller? Similar to how it is shown originally. Is there a way to have two rows with three links in each row aligned like I have it in the fourth screen capture? Also, when I look at the website in large view the navbar is no longer one row of links. The links for Web Design and Blog are on a separate line when I tried it. Do you have another suggestion? Thank you

Is there way to make the active link smaller? Yes, add display: flex as well to the .nav-item elements. I have updated my answer. Is there a way to have two rows with three links in each row That's how my code behaves on smaller screens. Also, when I look at the website in large view the navbar is no longer one row of links. No. If I view my example in full screen, I only see 1 row of links.

Thank you for your updated answer.  With the large view, in the answer you provided I don’t think it takes into account the empty svg and portfolio span in the original code. I have updated my question to include a screen capture of I what I am seeing when I add your answer.  I looked online to try and understand flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis. Why is flex-grow and flex shrink = 0? Is my understanding of flex-basis correct? It’s adding specific pixel space to the link area equally.  Each link area is 150 px of space? Thank you for your help with this

I researched further. Flex-grow-0 and flex-shrink-0 prevents it from growing and shrinking. Flex-basis is the specific pixels for the link area. Is there something that can be done about the container with the word Portfolio so that the links line up on one line?

Maybe this is not better way, buy you can try this :
 <header>
<div className="container fixed-top bg-white py-3">
  <header className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
    <a
      href="/"
      className="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none"
    >
      <svg className="bi me-2" width={40} height={32}>
        <use xlinkHref="#bootstrap" />
      </svg>
      <span className="fs-4">Portfolio</span>
    </a>
    <ul className="nav nav-pills">
      <div className="row">
        <li className="nav-item col-sm-2 col-4">
          <a href="#" className="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
            About
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item col-sm-2  col-4">
          <a href="#" className="nav-link">
            PowerPoint
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item col-sm-2  col-4">
          <a href="#" className="nav-link">
            Infographics
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item col-sm-2 col-4">
          <a href="#" className="nav-link">
            Logos and Icons
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item col-sm-2 col-4">
          <a href="#" className="nav-link">
            Web Design
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item col-sm-2 col-4">
          <a href="#" className="nav-link">
            Blog
          </a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </header>
</div>

Most of the time in these situations, using bootstrap grid system saves life.

Instead of using your own written css to style the links, why not use bootstrap classes for breakpoints on the elements you want to style differently on smaller screens.
For example, you can set mx-sm-auto or ms-sm-5 and me-sm-5 on the powerpoint link to make it behave differently on smaller screens.
You can read more about bootstrap breakpoints here Breakpoints-v5 and spacing here Spacing-v5

Thank you for your answer. How would this be written? Would it be written like this:
PowerPoint
I am not sure if what I wrote above is correct. It doesn’t look different when I tried it.
Looking at the link you provided for spacing. It’s (m)margin (s)start (sm)small view-5 which means times 3 spacing?  Is there a way to adjust the position with pixels? I don’t think times 3 spacing is large enough or would line up specifically where I would like but I might have written the above statement incorrectly.

This answer makes no sense unless you provide a working example.
